# TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.shape" (type TFOpLambda)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to make image patches from a pre-trained Xception model. When I take an input image and then apply  `tf.image.extract_patches` it generates this error `TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.shape" (type TFOpLambda).`.

```
   # Load the pre-trained Xception model to be used as the base encoder.
   xception = keras.applications.Xception(
     include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
   )
   
   for layer in xception.layers:
     layer.trainable = trainable
   

   inputs = layers.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="image_input")
   # Preprocess the input image.

   
   patches = tf.image.extract_patches(images=inputs,
                                sizes=[1, 32, 32, 1],
                                strides=[1, 32, 32, 1],
                                rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                                padding='VALID')

   
   patches = tf.shape(patches, (None, 73, 73, 1))

   xception_input = 
   tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input(patches)
   
   embeddings = xception(xception_input)
  
   return keras.Model(inputs, embeddings, name="vision_encoder")
```

Errors.

```
    TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.shape" (type 
    TFOpLambda).

    Expected DataType for argument 'out_type' not (None, 73, 73, 1).

    Call arguments received:
       • input=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 9, 9, 3072), dtype=float32)
       • out_type=('None', '73', '73', '1')
       • name=None
```

Comment: What does your input shape mean? (None, 2, 2, 30000)

Comment: I don't know why is it showing like this! it should be something like (1, 4, 100, 100) because I want to to make patches of a single example having width and height 100.

Comment: I'm very confused about what you're doing here `patches = tf.shape(patches, (None, 73, 73, 1))`. You're getting the shape of data and passing it as an input to preprocess_input fn.

Comment: Hi, I have created another question here  with detail [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248420/input-to-reshape-is-a-tensor-with-497664-values-but-the-requested-shape-has-307)